# p:selectCheckboxMenu component select all check box not updating bakingbean value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi Please check Below two image.
on p:selectCheckboxMenu  component when i select highlighted in image select all default check box and click on submit button it show "no record found" in dialogue box instead of this dialogue box is should show all movie name.

Even you can test this on primefaces showcase as well.

Please look into this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what's the question? You think it's a bug in primefaces?

Comment: Work perfectly for me.

You talking about this web page?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectCheckboxMenu.jsf

Comment: @L.Butz can't say about bug, but i fount its not work for me so just want to make notice.
In show case first time it work for me as well try repeatedly 2-3 times same process without refreshing page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes..this is a bug in primefaces...I faced the same thing in my code....Also this is present in the showcase page.

Select all works fine if it is the first checkbox to be selected, but does not work later. The selected list does not populate with the columns. Strangely enough, the deselect all works just fine whenever clicked.

Comment: Thanks god, Finally someone faces problem what i have faced.
Please provide solution.

Comment: This is now fixed by primefaces in the latest version.

Comment: It is not still worked for me. I am using primefaces 5.3

Comment: seems to be working in the show case (Used chrome). Have a look - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

Yes it seems to be a bug, you can try it on the showcase (done on chrome 30.0.1599.101).

- Check only one movie
- Submit -> It's OK
- Now check the "select all"
- Submit -> NOK

Comment: Same thing I am trying to tell all.

Answer (score 1):

This issue fixed in latest version. New prime faces component are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try again with another browser... I can't make it with IE7 here, but it works fine with Chrome/Firefox

Note that just because the showcase is not working as expected, it doesn't mean that the component is not working. It could be some kind of compatibility problem with your web browser and the AJAX event, for example.

I can tell you that i use this component here and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue fixed in latest version. New prime faces component are awesome. 
I have faced same issue with older version.